# Flows stopped due to missing node types: ui_base

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

Node-Red dashboard on IBM Cloud stopped working on 24 SEP after it worked properly for some months.
Node-Red Dashboard nodes have been installed initially. The app hasn’t been changed for a while. Couldn’t find any errors in the log so far, not sure what to look for either.

Comment: What version of NodeJS is your app running on?

Comment: I’m using the Node-RED Starter, so not aware of the underlying Node version. And thought, I don’t have to care. Tried node -v in the SSH of the app: command not found.

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of NodeJS your application is deployed on.

Most likely the app has restaged at some point and upgraded some of it's components which now require at least NodeJS 8.x.

NodeJS 6.x went EOL around June 2019

If you enable the continuous integration feature in IBM Cloud you should be able to edit the apps `package.json` and change the `engines` entry to bump it up to a supported version of NodeJS (I suggest NodeJS v10)